# copy and running configfiles programatically in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

There is a ansible code i am writing. It does two tasks, first is to copy a configuration file to target instance in groups. Second is running that config file to install the application.

I am creating configuration file and inventory programtically so that same suffix is added to both configfile name & groupname in inventory:

```
Configfile name example :            Equivalent group names:
myappconf1                             [myapp1]
                                       hostname
myappconf2                             [myapp2]
                                       hostname
```

This is my code for **copying files**

```
hosts: all
tasks:
name: Copy file.role1 to host1
 copy: src=/tmp/myconf1 dest=/tmp
 when:
  - "'myapp1' in group_names"


name: Copy Config File two to  to Ldap2
 copy: src=/tmp/myconf2 dest=/tmp
 when:
  - "'myapp2' in group_names"
```

This is my code for **running conf file**

```
hosts: myapp1
tasks:
  - command: "/tmp/mainapp/update.sh -f myappconf1"

hosts: myapp2
tasks:
  - command: "/tmp/mainapp/update.sh -f myappconf1"
```

But depending on user input uncertain number of conf files and groups can be created so I would like to do task more programatically. **desired code may look like**:

```
[task for copying file]
hosts: ~(myapp)
tasks:
- copy: copy the appropriate file to the host 
        example: copy myappconf4 to myapp4
- command: run the commmand with appropirate file
           example: for myapp3, command: /tmp/mainapp/update.sh -f myappconf3
```

Can someone please suggest me what i can use to make my code more generic and efficient ?

Comment: What is the source of truth for the elements that need to be configured?

Comment: Hi.. sorry I didn't understand what you mean ? the configuration file and inventory file is being created by a python code. User enter his desired configurations in the input file which is provided to python code. Then python code creates rest of the files.

Comment: What determines what needs to be configured?

Comment: I provided some addtional details in my last comment : the configuration file and inventory file is being created by a python code. User enter his desired configurations in the input file which is provided to python code. Then python code creates rest of the files

Comment: Hi Techraf... do you have any solution to my usecase ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group variables like this,

```
#File : "myapp1/group_vars/all/vars_file.yml"
# Application settings
app_name: "myapp1"
copy_file: "myapp1conf1"
.
.
# other variables used for myapp1
```

Then use 2nd folder for 2nd app

```
#File : "myapp2/group_vars/all/vars_file.yml"
# Application settings
copy_file: "myapp2conf2"
.
.
# other variables used for myapp2
```

And In your code modify as below,

```
hosts: all
-tasks
    -name: Copy file.role1 to host1
     copy: src=/tmp/{{ copy_file }} dest=/tmp

    -name : execute script
     command: "/tmp/mainapp/update.sh -f {{ app_name }}"
```

Now depending upon the environment use the user input during the play time as below,

```
ansible-play -i myapp1 main.yml
    or
ansible-play -i myapp2 main.yml
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the suggestion. But user will be running ansible-playbook only once. Can you please suggest what need to be done to run this in 1 go ?

Comment: In 1 go then you can have multiple variables for each application and use the same for copying and executing

Comment: I also thought the same... i used my python code to generate variables... you can check the answer i posted. If you hae any ohter solution then it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I populated variables with my python code in below format to resolve the issue:

```
[myapp]
host1 conf_file="myappconf1"
host2 conf_file="myappconf2"
```

then in my code i used the variable for both copy and running configfile tasks.